# Parsing program config files

Tags: c++, parsing

I need to write reader class for a program config file, and I'm trying to determine the best way to approach this.

I have some experience with **boost::spirit** (actually, just enough to know that I am terrible at writing grammars), and a good bit of experience with **regular-expressions**.

Other than that, I can't think of much. So my options seem to be:

1. boost::spirit
2. std or boost regex
3. ol' fashion string parsing

I am looking for suggestions or advice on how to proceed - or even pseudo-code should anyone feel inclined.

I realize this is a bit of an *opinion-based* question, but I'm really struggling with writers-block here. I'm worried I'll start down a path, and waste a lot of time before realizing it was a poor choice.

The config file format is already defined, and looks like this:

```
Group1 {
    Scalar1 = 500
    Scalar2 = 45.5
    Scalar3 = My Value
    List1 {
        LS1 = 123
        LS2 = hello world
    }
    List2 {
        LS1 = 456
        LS2 = goodbye world
    }
    Array1 [
        300
        200
        25
    ]
    Array2 [
        true
        false
        true
        false
    ]
};
```

- The config will always have at least one `Group`.
- A `Group` will contain *0..n* `Scalar`, `List`, and/or `Array` entries
- A `scalar` is: `label = value`
- A `List` is a labeled container of `Scalars`
- An `Array` is a labeled container of values

The labels shown (eg. `Scalar1`, `Scalar2`, ...) are just examples. They can be called anything: `maxrate = 500`, `avg_val = 45.5`, would have been just as valid.

Comment: quick question: why do you want to define your own config format when there are already quite a few config formats out there?

Comment: @DZDomi Thanks for the comment. The config format is already defined. I need to write a lib to conform to the format that is already in use. I didn't make that clear. If you have a suggestion, though, I could propose changing the format  as a possible path.

Comment: The language looks small. IMHO, unless you have extensive experience with Boost::Spirit, Flex or Bison, write your own. I could write this up faster than I could get the above tools working.  I recommend in any case, draw a parsing diagram and maybe also BNF format.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews beat me to it. Only thing I'd add is I don't think Regex is a good fit for this one.

Comment: Look up recursive descent parsing, this would be very easy and clean done that way.  Unless you have a grammar for numeric literals I'd just define them as "whatever strtod and strtol parse"

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I was thinking the same. My biggest concern though, are the scalar values, which can be strings. And the strings could contain []{} characters. This would complicate things a little as I'd have to be careful to match openings  and closings. I didn't know if a grammar would be better suited for that reason.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister Not sure how I missed that. It's perfect for recursive descent - and I already have some code I can reuse. Thanks

Comment: @BlairFonville Glad to hear it.  For strings and such, I'd write a regexp to try to suck them out.

Comment: I never said to not develop a grammar.  Some grammars are not worth the hassle of the big tools.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No, you’re right. In fact you specifically said that I should. I misspoke - I meant to write “I didn’t know if a grammar library would better suited”. If I could trust that there would be no human error, the parsing would be trivial. My primary goal is robust error detection and handling. That’s where it gets most complicated. I probably should have stated that in the question.

Comment: See my article on how to write a recursive descent parser.  This is actually pretty easy.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the file to tmp, replacing every instance of `=` with `:`, then read it as json with `boost::ptree`.

Comment: While this doesn't work "out of the box", I can definitely work with this, and it's probably the quickest path to take. It's just what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: you're wellcome. The config syntax was really similar to json. Actually if  the assignment were replaced with colon, it'd be json.

Comment: I also had to add commas after each entry, and wrap entry names and string values (where values included spaces) in quotes. But it was a quick fix, and gave me the error detection that I needed.